# OllyDbg on win7 64 bit

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I've been following along lena151's tutorials on reverse engineering and all is going well except for unpacking. I'm running olly on a 64 bit windows 7 machine and it works fine except when the EP is always "JMP 71B00000" after following the jump an address is moved into EAX and then another one into ECX. A call is made to ECX and I get an exception that I can't pass to the program. This only happens when I step the code from the EP though. Could anyone explain to me what this is?

Comment: You seem to try unpacking a packed EXE. These programs are highly optimized and some are obfuscated and includes anti debugging codes. Looking at the given instruction, you're likely stepped in to a trap.

Comment: but even unpacked programs have this same EP. Could it be part of windows?

Comment: I think you are seeing some anti-debugging technique in action.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917336/ollydbg-incorrectly-replaces-lines-with-jmp-71b00000-in-win7x64 ?

Answer (score 1):

Ollydbg cannot disassemble the binaries for 64-bit processor. I think you'd be better off with a virtual machine running a x86_32 system.

And from [OllyDbg 2.0's page](http://www.ollydbg.de/version2.html):

> And once again: no, this version does not work under Win64!